# checking string value is in the file that was read

Tags: c++, file, if-statement

I'm starting in the C++ language.

I created a file that contains some numbers:

**eleitores.txt**

```
111111111111  
222222222222   
121212121212  
131313131313
```

The code reads that file:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream input("eleitores.txt");
    string titulo_numerais;

    for(string linha; getline(input, linha);){
        titulo_numerais = linha +="\n";
        cout << titulo_numerais;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I need to check if the value of a variable is equal to one of the four numbers that are in the .txt file.

```cpp
string aa = "131313131313";
ifstream input("eleitores.txt");
string titulo_numerais;

for(string linha; getline(input, linha);){
    titulo_numerais = linha +="\n";
    if (aa == titulo_numerais){
        cout << "- " << titulo_numerais;
    }
```

As a beginner, I don't understand how the C++ language makes this comparison. I haven't found a solution that does this check and only returns the correct number.

Comment: An equality comparison usually checks if two objects are equal. Since your `titulo_numerais` is used to store the entire contents of the file read, you are comparing whether everything in there is the same as your `aa` string. I believe you want to check if `aa == linha` instead?

Comment: check if 131313131313 of variable **aa**  exists in the file...

Comment: Yes, but it is not the entire file, just one line of it. So you obviously need to check if the line you just read has that value

Comment: You probably want to use find(): [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and maybe instead of using the whole file in the search maybe you want to use the `linha` variable for your find so that you limit the search to just the last line read.

Comment: Get the variable from the user and then as you are reading in the file, check to see if each line matches the variable as the line is read in. Save you from having to store the file contents and from needing a second loop to compare that which was read against the user's input.

Comment: so the integer 131313131313 will not be checked.. but 1 and then 3 and then 1 in this way...

Comment: You should try to explain what you think `titulo_numerais = linha +="\n";` does.  Your explanation hopefully mentions that the last character in your string will be `'\n'` and that string will never be equal to another string that _doesn't_ end in `'\n'`.

Comment: @stack.cardoso Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. This returns the found item:

```
% ./main
131313131313
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string aa = "131313131313";

    ifstream input("eleitores.txt");
    string titulo_numerais;

    for(string linha; getline(input, linha);){
        titulo_numerais = linha;
        if (aa == titulo_numerais) {
            cout << titulo_numerais + "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```